# Find the largest duration between timespans in list of timespans

Tags: c#, timespan

I have written this code to find the largest timespan gap between ordered timespans. It's working correctly but is there a more efficient way of accomplishing this as this could get really slow if there is a lot of items in the list?

```
var events = this.Events.OrderBy(x => x.TimeSinceStart).ToList();

var largestTime = events.FirstOrDefault().TimeSinceStart;

for(int i = 0; i < events.Count() - 1; i ++)
{
    var difference = events[i + 1].TimeSinceStart - events[i].TimeSinceStart;

    if (difference > largestTime)
        largestTime = difference;
}
```

Comment: Where are the events coming from? If from a database some SQL to report this would probably be possible and also possibly more efficient.

Comment: Its actually coming from the database but as json which is deserialized, so this check will probably always be in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm complexity can't improve because it's already in its optimal state (`O(nlogn)` for sorting) but you can improve overall performance by skipping `TimeSpan` comparison using `Ticks`:

```
var eventTicks = this.Events.Select(x => x.TimeSinceStart.Ticks).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

var largestTime = eventTicks.FirstOrDefault();

for (int i = 0; i < eventTicks.Count - 1; i++)
{
    var difference = eventTicks[i + 1] - eventTicks[i];

    if (difference > largestTime)
        largestTime = difference;
}

var maxGap = TimeSpan.FromTicks(largestTime);
```